# django query to calculate time

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

The following are the timestamps that is present in the timestamp column of the table userdata.My question is that how to write a query such that i get the output as i need the month name i.2,2010-03 and the total time used in the month

```
   userdata.months.filter().order_by('-timestamp')




 '2011-03-07 16:03:01'
 '2011-03-07 16:07:04'
 '2011-03-06 11:03:01'
 '2011-03-08 16:03:01'
 '2011-03-04 09:03:01'
 '2011-05-16 16:03:01'
 '2011-05-18 16:03:01'
 '2011-07-16 12:03:01'
 '2011-07-17 12:03:01'
 '2011-07-17 15:03:01'
```

Comment: what do you mean by the total time used? do you have a start and end date? if it's your question I asked nearly same a few time ago... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month to filter by mount then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669875/how-to-aggregate-computed-field-with-django-orm-without-raw-sql to sum durations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
my_month = 2 (or whatever you need)
userdata.months.filter(timestamp__month=my_month).aggregate(sum('timestamp__time')
```

i'm not sure about that timestamp__time, you may search a bit about it, but i think it's correct.
otherwise, you can use a raw query (userdata.months.raw('query here'))

Comment: datetime columns can't be summed by database. (I had this problem in a question)